# a bug in grid in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

**I was creating a chess board in `tkinter` when I found a bug**
this is my code

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import Button

class Board(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master,bg="#333")

        self.gm=GameManager()
        
        for row in reversed(range(8)):
            for column in range(8):
                
                self.grid_columnconfigure(row+column, weight = 1)
                self.grid_rowconfigure(row+column, weight = 1)
                
                p = Piece(self,row+column+1)
                p.grid(row=row,column=column,sticky="nsew")
                self.gm.addPeice(p)

        self.gm._start()

                

class GameManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # pegs
        # white
        self.wR = Peg("peg/wR.png")
        self.wQ = Peg("peg/wQ.png")
        self.wP = Peg("peg/wP.png")
        self.wN = Peg("peg/wN.png")
        self.wK = Peg("peg/wK.png")
        self.wB = Peg("peg/wB.png")

        # black
        self.bR = Peg("peg/bR.png")
        self.bQ = Peg("peg/bQ.png")
        self.bP = Peg("peg/bP.png")
        self.bN = Peg("peg/bN.png")
        self.bK = Peg("peg/bK.png")
        self.bB = Peg("peg/bB.png")

        self._call=0

        self.board=[0]*64

    def addPeice(self,b):
        self.board[self._call]=b
        self._call+=1

    def _start(self):
        # white
        
        self.board[0].config(image=self.wR.getImage)
        self.board[1].config(image=self.wN.getImage)
        self.board[2].config(image=self.wB.getImage)
        self.board[3].config(image=self.wQ.getImage)
        self.board[4].config(image=self.wK.getImage)
        self.board[5].config(image=self.wB.getImage)
        self.board[6].config(image=self.wN.getImage)
        self.board[7].config(image=self.wR.getImage)


class Peg(object):
    def __init__(self,imgpath):
        super().__init__()

        self.imag = imgpath
    
        self.getImage = PhotoImage(file=self.imag)


class Piece(Button):
    def __init__(self,master,pl):
        super().__init__(master, height=20,width=20,bd=0)

        if pl%2:
            self.config(bg="#fff",activebackground='#fff')
        else:
            self.config(bg="#000",activebackground='#000')

class Hatsman(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.run()
        self.mainloop()

    def run(self):

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # specify geometry
        self.geometry("800x650+250+20")

        # add board
        self.board = Board(self)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        self.board.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Hatsman()
```

This is the result
[image]

but it works fine before 8th image is added
[image]

Comment: how can i add more images to the button in the grid

Comment: If one of the cell in the last row does not have an image, the row height will be the same as other rows, i.e. *20 lines height*.  However, when all the cells at the last row have images, then the row height will be *20 pixels height* which is much smaller than that of other rows.  Due to `weight=1` are set to all rows, the last row having smaller row height is squeezed to zero height.  If you add `uniform=1` to all rows, then you will see the last row no matter whether there is cell without image or not.

Comment: 'uniform=1' make rows smaller when 8th image is added

Comment: It is expected because you have fixed window size 800x650.